# Problem approving allowance using external Metamask Account with local Ganache

Tags: web3js, truffle, metamask, ethereumjs, ganache

I am using React, to interact with a smart contract deployed on local Ganache, I can approve allowances to accounts generated by Ganache, but I can't approve allowance with Metamask accounts which aren't.

`await tokenContract.methods.approve(farmContractAddress, amount).call({ from: userAccount })`

Using this, I tried using:

```
window.ethereum
        .request({
            method: 'wallet_requestPermissions',
            params: [{
                eth_accounts: {
                    requiredMethods: ['signTypedData_v3']
                }
            }],
        })
```

but I don't understand which methods can be added in the `requiredMethods` param, to require the user to 'Approve' them.

PS: I am a beginner. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a personal project I made on react also using Metamask I used `eth_requestAccounts` like this, as you can see [in my code](https://github.com/JulzCryptoMyriad/JulzWidget/blob/4ba9d3e8c5926742f03e31d00c5eaa5ee5fad225/julzwidgetapp/src/components/PaymentComponent.js#L74):

`await window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });`